# Does Hello World app created with TideSDK need SDK to run on another computer?

Tags: tidesdk

I installed TideSDK and TideSDK Developer correctly in Ubuntu and Windows 7. I can run Developer, import Hello World project, can run the app and do a Package with Runtime. Followed the "Get Started With TideSDK" tutotial.

The app generated can run without problems in my own system (Ubuntu or Windows 7, depends where it was compiled), but when I try to run it in a computer that doesn't have TideSDK, it doesn't run. Why?

Do I need to install TideSDK in each computer where the app will run?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to install the TideSDK on each client computer.. the installer created with option: "Package with Runtime" would be the only binary you need to ship.